# .Net app when started gives error 0x80131418 - Failed to grant permission to execute

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I have a .Net 3.5 application compiled in VS2008 that when run after a Debug compile gives me the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'MyProgram, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant permission to execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131418)

The same program when compiled in Release mode runs successfully. My svn logs indicate the solution or project files have not been modified. Any ideas how I can tackle ths problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in your bin folder and make sure that your `.dll` files are not set to read-only. This sometimes happen to me while using source control as well

Comment: None of the .dll files are read-only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one of your components isn't re-compiling.  I would go through your Build properties.  (Under Properties of your solution.  Configuration section.)

Make sure they are all marked to Build and then try again.

Comment: Your suggestion was not applicable as all of the projects were checked to be built but I did notice under "Common Properties"/"Debug Source Files" there was an entry in the "Do not look for these source files". Why it is there I do not know. I deleted that entry and rebuilt. Voila! All is fine.